# Collapse rows by columns in R repeated values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data

```
data.orig <- data.frame(
          id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1),
          start = c(0, 47, 103, 194, 277, 350, 453, 522),
          end = c(47, 103, 194, 277, 350, 453, 522, 603),
          event = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    )
```

I would like to obtain the following dataset, collapsing the rows that contain the same event value by id, but having repeated values

```
data.targ <- data.frame(
          id = c(1,1,1,1),
          start = c(0, 47, 194, 277),
          end = c(47, 194, 277, 603),
          event = c(1, 0, 1, 0)
    )
```

I have already tried group_by and summarize, but I do not find the correct combination

Comment: The first `data.frame` is not a valid `data.frame`. `id` and `event` have a length of 6, `start` and `end` 7.

Comment: Solved both issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fairly close! The issue with directly using group-by is it is impossible to differentiate same id and event in non-consecutive rows. Therefore, we can add `consecutive_id` (introduced in dplyr v1.1.0):

```
library(dplyr)
data.orig %>%
  group_by(grp=consecutive_id(id,event),id,event) %>%
  reframe(start=min(start,na.rm=TRUE),
            end=max(end,na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  select(-grp)

# A tibble: 4 × 4
     id event start   end
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     0    47
2     1     0    47   194
3     1     1   194   277
4     1     0   277   603
```

Alternatively, we can replace min/max with head/tail:

```
data.orig %>%
  group_by(grp=consecutive_id(id,event),id,event) %>%
  reframe(start=head(start,1),
          end=tail(end,1)) %>%
  select(-grp)

# A tibble: 4 × 4
     id event start   end
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     0    47
2     1     0    47   194
3     1     1   194   277
4     1     0   277   603
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach with `dplyr` and `tidyr` could be...

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
  start = c(0, 47, 103, 194, 277, 350, 453),
  end = c(47, 103, 194, 277, 350, 453, 522),
  event = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,0 )
)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 |> 
  mutate(grp = cumsum(c(0, abs(diff(event))))) |> 
  pivot_longer(c(start, end)) |> 
  group_by(id, event, grp) |> 
  summarise(min = min(value),
           max = max(value)) |>
  select(-grp) |> 
  rename(start = min, end = max) |> 
  arrange(start)

#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#> # Groups:   id, event [2]
#>      id event start   end
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     0    47
#> 2     1     0    47   194
#> 3     1     1   194   277
#> 4     1     0   277   522
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data |>
  mutate(helper = cumsum(event)) |>
  group_by(id, event, helper) |>
  summarise(
    start = min(start),
    end = max(end)
  ) |>
  arrange(helper,-event) |>
  select(id, start, end, event)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'id', 'event'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#> # Groups:   id, event [2]
#>      id start   end event
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     0    47     1
#> 2     1    47   194     0
#> 3     1   194   277     1
#> 4     1   277   522     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively

```r
data.targ <- data.orig %>% mutate(lag=lag(event), 
lag2=coalesce(ifelse(event==0,NA,event),lag), 
max=max(end), .by=id) %>% 
  filter(lag2==1) %>% mutate(end2=last(end), 
end=ifelse(end==end2,max,end), .by=id) %>% 
  select(-c(lag,lag2,max,end2))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
  id start end event
1  1     0  47     1
2  1    47 103     0
3  1   194 277     1
4  1   277 603     0
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is first grouped by "id" in this code using the group_by function, and a new column called "event_repeat" is then created using mutate and rep. Based on which row has the highest "start" value within each group, the "event_repeat" column repeats values from each group.
You will receive a changed dataset named 'collapsed_data' after executing this program in RStudio or any other R environment of your choice. Rows having similar event values are collapsed by ID while keeping repeated values.
Please be aware that I have modified your original dataset for demonstration reasons to add other events.

## Install and load required packages

install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

```
# Define your original dataset
data <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1),
  start = c(0, 47, 103, 194, 277, 350),
  end = c(47, 103, 194, 277, 350 ,453),
   event = c(0 ,0 ,0 ,2 ,3 ,4)
)

# Collapse rows with the same event value by id and repeat values
collapsed_data <- data %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(event_repeat = rep(event[which.max(start)], length.out = n())) 

print(collapsed_data)
```